# SSLProtocolException: SSL Handshake terminated: ssl=0xce70fa40: failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error

Tags: java, android, ssl

For Android 7.0 and 7.1, I am getting following error for one of our servers

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0xce70fa40: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:610 0xcf5dfda0:0x00000001)
error:1000009a:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_clnt.c:764 0xe3062196:0x00000000)
```

Also here is my `http-client` code looks like to call the server in android application

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder().url(urlStr).build();

Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();

Map<String, List<String>> headers = response.headers().toMultimap();
byte[] contents = null;

contents = response.body().toString().getBytes();
```

I have tried all the possible solutions that have been mentioned on SO, but nothing has worked. If I go back to Android 6.0 and below, everything seems to be working fine. I am not sure if this is a cipher suites issue. I will try to grab a wireshark network handshake and post it here.

Does anyone have any idea?

This is what nmap provides about ciphersuites

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE
XXX/tcp open  snpp
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.0:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|     warnings:
|       64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|       Broken cipher RC4 is deprecated by RFC 7465
|       Ciphersuite uses MD5 for message integrity
|   TLSv1.1:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|     warnings:
|       64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|       Broken cipher RC4 is deprecated by RFC 7465
|       Ciphersuite uses MD5 for message integrity
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|     warnings:
|       64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|       Broken cipher RC4 is deprecated by RFC 7465
|_  least strength: C
```

Comment: *"I have tried all the possible solutions that have been mentioned on SO, but nothing has worked."* - which says exactly nothing what you actually tried. My guesses: either your server  still requires SSLv3, has only insecure ciphers like RC4 configured or croaks on ciphers or TLS extensions he does not know instead of ignoring these. But nothing is really known about the server so these are just blind guesses.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - I get your point, I will find out more from wireshark trace. I was wondering if there are any other issues for Android 7.0 and above related to this.